# Join several arrays with jQuery .each() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to create an array from a number of div id's. Here is my code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#content > div[id^=post]').each(function(){
        var ele = Number($(this).attr('id').substr(5,4));
        var arr = $.makeArray(ele);
    });
});
```

I have a list of numbers in my ele variable and I want to join these numbers into one array. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show your HTML please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var arr = $('#content > div[id^="post"]').map(function(){
    return Number($(this).attr('id').substr(5,4));
}).toArray();
```

Comment: +1, but I'd suggest [`toArray`](http://api.jquery.com/toarray/) over `get`, merely for clarity. No functional difference of course.

Comment: The only thing I would change is `$(this).attr('id')` to `this.id`, really more of a personal preference if anything. That and double quotes around `post`, but that's getting really picky.

Comment: @KevinB: Actually, IIRC, the `"` is required.

Comment: Awsome. Now I can get the greatest number in the array and style accordingly: var featurePost = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
$('#post-' + featurePost).css('background','#fff');

Comment: The `"` are not required if the attribute value that should be matched doesn't have any whitespace. (`id`s may not have whitespace anyways but `alt` for instance does.). It's a good practice to use them nevertheless.